# populate selectbox jquery using php array

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays

i have a little question here...
i have a PHP array like this..

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idCustomer] => 2553
            [session] => 
            [noMobil] => 666
            [keterangan] => Sistem
            [tahun] => 2012
            [merk] => Sistem
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [idCustomer] => 2553
            [session] => 
            [noMobil] => 7777
            [keterangan] => hahahaha
            [tahun] => 2120
            [merk] => 
        )

)
```

And i stored that array to `**$_SESSION[datamobil]**`..
and then my question is.. how to populate that array into selectbox using jquery.. so the select box is like this..

```
<select id='mobil' name='mobil'>
<option> - PILIH MOBIL - </option>
<option value='666'>666</option>
<option value='7777'>7777</option>
</select>
```

and when i select **one** of that selectbox option.. it will populate the **detail** element... like this

```
selectbox : [-- 666 --] <-- the selectbox
- Detail -
keterangan : Sistem
tahun : 2012
merk : Sistem
```

any one can help me?? thanks before

EDIT :

a code to get the array..

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM customer_car WHERE idCustomer = '$_SESSION[idCustomer]'";
        $go = $db->query($query);
        $mobil_array = array();
        while($car = $go->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $mobil_array = $car;
        }
        $_SESSION[datamobil] = $mobil_array;
```

Comment: We're happy to help but not create your code from scratch. Please show some attempt in this and paste what you have so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting that array using `jquery ajax`..? if yes..  consider the whole array is assigned to a variable `arrayvariable`  so in the jquery side, you can give the code as

```
var replacetext="<option value=''> - PILIH MOBIL - </option>";
for(var i=0; i<arrayvariable.length;i++)
{
 replacetext+="<option value='"+arrayvariable[i]+"'>"+arrayvariable['i']['noMobil']+"</option>";
}
$('#mobil').html(replacetext);
```

and you can use the jquery [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event. to display the details of the particular mobile..

**EDIT**

in your case
if the variable is stored in the session.get the variable and do the same for loop in php

```
$sesionvariable=$_SESSION[datamobil];
echo "<select id='mobil' name='mobil'><option> - PILIH MOBIL - </option>";
for ($i=0;$i<=count($sesionvariable);$i++)
{
echo "<option value='".$sesionvariable[$i]."'>".$sesionvariable[$i]['noMobil']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

and use the onload [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event for that select box.

hope this helps..

Comment: i get that array from $_SESSION.. because i store the array on SESSION.. i've just insert the code to get an array for my case.